# automate exe installation in AWS ec2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there any way to install exe/MSI agents in AWS EC2 instances in an automated way?? In specific, I am looking for a counterpart of Azure's Custom Script Extension. [Free of cost]

Scenario:
I want to install BigFix and Datadog agents on 1000 Ec2 instances, this is a one time job, so I am not looking for any solution that involves Chef / Puppet, etc.,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass a script to the instance that will be executed on the first boot (but not thereafter). It is often referred to as a **User Data script**.

See:

- [Running Commands on Your Windows Instance at Launch - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-user-data.html)
- [Running Commands on Your Linux Instance at Launch - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html)

If you wish to install *after* the instance has started, use the [AWS Systems Manager Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html).

Comment: Thank you John. I am specifically looking for intalling agents on machines that are already running (production workloads). We have about ~3000 virtual machines and the pre-requisite for having Systems Manager is to install SSM agents on all 3000 servers. How can we automate installing SSM agents on those many machines with those many Keys.

Comment: Ah, Chicken vs Egg! In that case, SSM cannot initially assist you. It looks like you'll need some manual work to install an agent that will help you in future.

Comment: When you say "with those many Keys", I'm hoping you are not using the randomly-generated EC2 keypairs / passwords on each separate instance? The recommendation is that, once an instance is launched, security should be configured to use the company standard (eg Active Directory or a common keypair) rather than using the AWS-generated keys/passwords. Might be something else to fix-up as you process each instance.

Comment: This process is when we onboard a new customer. We usually install the agents before we officially support (Steady state) the customer. Meaning, we will not get AD credentials until the project-transition is complete and agent installation is part of project-transition.